# Question about Principal ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, principal-ideal-domains

I'm mathematics student. I just confusing about some basic concept, so I ask for it here...

First of all, principal ideal means ideal generated by a single element, but I don't know what 'generated' means.. How 'Generated' is defined?

I saw some examples on Dummit's book, and they say 'The trivial ideal 0 and the ideal R are both principal: 0=(0) and R=(1)'. My second question is, if ring R is principal, then its ideals are always principal?

Thank you for read, and I also hope you answer for my few questions!

Comment: *The ideal generated by some elements* $a_1$, ..., $a_n$ is, by definition, the smallest ideal that contains the elements $a_1$, ..., $a_n$. For your second question, yes : the definition of a principal ring is a ring whose all ideals are principal.

Comment: A ring with identity is a principal ideal in itself because it is generated by $1$ but that doesn't make it a principal ideal domain.

Answer (score 3):

In general, if $R$ is a ring and $S\subseteq R$ is a subset then the ideal generated by $S$ is defined as the intersection of all ideals which contain $S$ as a subset. In other words this is the smallest ideal (by inclusion) which contains $S$. The notation is $(S)$.

In particular, if $S=\{a\}$ is a set with one element then $(a)$ is the smallest ideal of $R$ which contains the element $a$. Now, if $R$ is a ring with unit then it is easy to see that the set:

$I=\{\sum_{i=1}^n r_ias_i: n\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\},\ r_i,\ s_i\in R\}$

Is an ideal which contains $a$. Hence $(a)\subseteq I$. On the other hand, $(a)$ itself is an ideal which contains $a$, thus by the properties of an ideal it must contain all the elements of $I$. So $I\subseteq (a)$ is also true. So this implies $I=(a)$, we found a relatively easy way to describe $(a)$.

If we also knew that $R$ is commutative then it would be even easier, then we would simply have $(a)=\{ra: r\in R\}$. (check it)

Alright, now to the definitions. An ideal $I$ is called principal if there is some $a\in I$ such that $I=(a)$. A ring $R$ is called a principal ring if all its ideals are principal.